# How to replace specific column numbers with values contained in an array

Tags: r

I have a matrix 'pnl12'(x rows, y columns) and two vectors: 'ttd' and 'ttm'.

```
no. of columns in 'pnl12' = length of ttd = length of ttm
```

Now I wish to select certain columns of pnl12 as:

```
pnl12[,(ttm < 1) & (ttd < 1) & (ttd<ttm) ]
```

or I can also have columns of pnl12 to be replaced as:

```
which((ttm < 1) & (ttd < 1) & (ttd<ttm))
```

Let's say , 3 columns gets selected satisfying above condition as 796th, 799th and 904th column.

Now I wish to replace all the values of these columns by a values in vector b

```
b = c(19, 26, 43)
```

So all values in 796th column of pnl12  will be replace by 19. All Values in 799th column will be replaced by 26. And all values in 904th column will be replaced by 43.

This vector b is generated as :

```
b = ead[(ttm < 1) & (ttd < 1) & (ttd<ttm)]*(1-rr[(ttm < 1) & (ttd < 1) & (ttd<ttm)]))
```

So, length of 'b' is same as no of columns selected in pnl12.

Can anybody please help me as how to do above replacement?

For example, I have a matrix:

```
1 2 3  
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Then column 2 and 3 are to be replace by 40 and 50, So result will be:

```
1 40 50 
4 40 50
7 40 50
```

How to achieve this in R?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would expand your replacement up to the right dimensions:

```
# setting up one of your examples
mm = matrix(1:9, 3)
b = c(2, 3)
x = c(40, 50)

# expand the replacement appropriately, then assign
xx = matrix(x, nrow = nrow(mm), ncol = length(x), byrow = TRUE)
mm[, b] = xx
mm
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1   40   50
# [2,]    2   40   50
# [3,]    3   40   50
```

Alternatively, there's nothing wrong with a simple `for` loop:

```
for (i in seq_along(b)) {
    mm[, i] = x[i]
}
```